# Is it Possible to Install Windows Service Pack from ISO Image?

Tags: windows, installation, iso, service-pack

We know that it is possible to  directly install Windows OS (or any OS) using ISO image without extracting it to a local folder by an end user.

I am using Oracle VirtualBox for creating multiple instance of Windows OS and all the time I have to extract and then install the Service Pack whose ISO image is kept in a central server machine.

So, is it possible to install a Windows Service Pack from an ISO image without extracting it to a local folder by the end user?

Comment: And where did you get this ISO image of the service pack?

Comment: @KonradGajewski: It can downloaded using MSDN subscription.

Comment: Any reason you cannot either download the OS media containing the service pack already, or slipstream the service pack into your install media?

Comment: @jscott: Getting service packs and all are done by our IT guys :) They gave me an ISO image path kept in a central server. Due to disk fragmentation problem they cannot keep it extracted.

Comment: Have the IT department get you the correct install media.  @massimo explains in more detail with their answer.

Comment: You can also go through the trouble of manually adding (the process is called "slipstreaming") updates to an older ISO. But it's really much, much easier to download a more recent one.

Comment: @Massimo Thanks for the advice on slipstreaming. I shall have a look into it.

Answer (score 5):

For each Windows OS, there are three types of ISOs you can download from MSDN or VLSC: the base install ISO containing the original (RTM) version of the OS; the service pack ISO containing only the service pack, which must be installed on a running system; and finally the latest ISO containing the OS already updated with the latest service pack (and/or additional updates).

The service pack ISO can only be used to update a running system; but if you download the latest ISO (usually described as such, otherwise you can just look at the release date) you can use it to install the most recent release of the OS.

For example, for Windows 7 you have:

- Windows 7 (original RTM release)
- Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (only the service pack)
- Windows 7 *with* Service Pack 1 (updated release already including the service pack)

For Windows 8.1, which doesn't have any service pack (yet), there still is an updated ISO which already contains several updates, including the major ones.

Comment: Can you use the OS+SP to UPGRADE a system by booting form this ISO?

Comment: No. The SP must be installed on a running system, the updated OS must be used to install a new system.

Comment: @Massimo As you said, one can use the most recent ISO image which contains all the recent updates. But when I have the OS in one image and  the SP1 in another image, is there a way that I can directly install the service pack? Also note that when there comes the SP2 at a later date, I will have to install it separately.

Comment: Yes, you can manually integrate service packs and updates in an existing ISO, and then install from that; this essentially is the same process Microsoft uses to build newer ISOs. It's a bit complex but it can be done; have a search for "slipstreaming" and you'll find plenty of tutorials around.

Comment: But you'll still have to extract the ISO contents and the updates, perform some operations and then repackage the ISO or simply save the files to a bootable external media; there's no way to accomplish this if you *only* have the OS ISO and the SP ISO and you can't freely work on them.

Answer (score 0):

An ISO is just an image of a filesystem on a CD/DVD. There is a type of ISO that is bootable, meaning that an entire (albeit limited) operating system is contained on the ISO. This is the type you would have as an operating system installation disk. So I honestly doubt if an ISO with a SP is able to boot. If you don't want to waste disk space, mount the ISO as a virtual drive (Daemon tools for example).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. mounting the ISO image as a virtual drive is a good option but our security policy doesn't allow installation of such tools.

Comment: I thought you were the admin :) Anyway, this is not much different from putting the CD in the drive.